# 'list' object has no attribute 'matmul'

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

I have the code below to compute Markov chain iterations. Having two matrices: the current state matrix and transitional matrix; when stating the number of iterations (multiplications between the two matrices) the code should save the result of the state matrix after one iteration for the next iteration, and so on. When compiling the code, there is an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'matmul'.

I'm working with NumPy version 1.17. How can I solve it?

```
import numpy as np

transitionalMatrix = ([0.42, 0.16, 0.36, 0.02 ],[0.05, 0.43, 0.04, 0.11 ], [0.24, 0.16, 0.51 , 0.04 ], [0.01, 0.31, 0.01, 0.59 ]) 
stateMatrix = ([0.20461531, 0.26104588, 0.19799357, 0.14561973]) 
maxIterations = 6

res = [stateMatrix]
for iteration in range(1, maxIterations):
 prev = res[iteration - 1]
 res.append(prev.matmul(transitionalMatrix))
```

Comment: What you've posted here shows, not a matrix, but a tuple of empty lists.  Since you did not supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't give you any specific advice or repair.  In general, it appears that you need to work through a tutorial on NumPy, to learn how to covert Python data structures to NumPy structures.

Comment: To see valid `methods` for `list`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists.  To see how to use `matmul`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are trying to apply matmul to a list, which doesn't have any such attribute. Assuming that what you want to use is `np.matmul()`, what you should be doing is:

```
np.matmul(prev, transitionalMatrix))
```

However, as Prune pointed out, the lack of a minimal, reproducible example makes it impossible to help you any further.